# Ready solution for manipulate images

Tags: php, gd, truetype

I'm searching for a class or function, to convert, add borders and text (using ttf fonts) to an uploaded image before the image is saved on the server. 
Do you know something?

Answer (score 3):

Check [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) and [Asido](http://asido.info/).

Comment: It looks like WideImage is still in active development.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is incredible and has many libraries for PHP

Comment: If you can use ImageMagick, go for it. It handles TTF rendering way better than plain GD.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library.

You can convert image types using the [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)/`png`/`gif` and [`imagejpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)/`png`/`gif` functions.

[`imagerectangle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php) for adding a border (draw a rectangle behind your image).

[`imagettftext`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) for adding text.

Lots of tutorials online, good luck!

Comment: What should I check in the uploaded image to make it hack save?

Comment: Sorry Tom, I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: Basically, if the tool of your choice manages to open a file and add a watermark to it, you can safely assume that it is a valid image. As long as you use move_uploaded_file() and consorts, there are no specific security risks that come to mind.